# In integration by parts, if 2 functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are of the same type, (in ILATE) which of the two do we take first in the formula??

Tags: calculus, integration

For, example, take a function $\int{f(x)g(x)}$, where $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are trigonometric functions.
As per the integration by parts formula, $$\int{f(x)g(x)d(x)} = f(x)\int{g(x)} - \int{\frac{df(x)}{dx}\int{g(x)}d(x)}$$

Acccording to the ILATE rule, the function having the highest precedence is taken first, but what if both the functions have the same precedence?

Comment: Give an example of a function. Generally we take g(x) as a function whose integration is known to us. For example consider sec⁵x can be considered as sec³x × sec²x and as the integral of sec²x is tan x, you should consider g(x)= sec²x

Comment: LIATE is not a rule; there are way too many exceptions. It’s just a vague mnemonic and “suggestion” for kiddos to follow when they have nothing better to try/ when teachers don’t really feel like teaching. In fact I would go so far as to even suggest you forget about this rule and just do a whole bunch of practice questions. The goal is to always simplify things and to ask yourself: which of the two functions is easy to integrate and which is easy to differentiate.

Comment: @SarbanBhattacharya For example, $\int{sin(x)cos(x)d(x)}$. Here, both sin(x) and cos(x) are of the same precedence. In this case, integration of sin(x) and cos(x) is known to us.

Comment: Then you should not be doing it using parts. In this case consider $sin(x)cos(x)=\frac{sin(2x)}{2}$. Then $\int{\frac{sin2x}{2}}=-\frac{cos2x}{4}$

Comment: Giving highest priority to inverse trig functions makes sense because they never integrate nicely. Next priority to logs also makes sense because they often integrate poorly but differentiate nicely. But after that it really depends on the integral. You need to look ahead and think "which of these will result in a simpler integrand".